# How to use an iterator in an implemented Queue

Tags: java

I have a task to code the below class ... I have a problem in iterator() method
I have many errors in it , I do not know how to do to correct it .. Can you suggest a way to correct the code under iterator() method ... You can as well see the other parts of the class ...I put the comments from eclipse next to each infected line.. thanks

```
package queue;
import java.util.*;

public class FifoQueue<E> extends AbstractQueue<E> implements Queue<E> {
    private QueueNode<E> last;
    private int size;

    public FifoQueue() {

    }

    /** 
     * Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue
     * @return an iterator over the elements in this queue
     */ 
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        QueueNode<E> position =last;
        Iterator itr = position.iterator(); // The method iterator() is //undefined for the type FifoQueue.QueueNode<E>- Iterator is a raw type. References //to generic type Iterator<E> should be 
     parameterized
        while(itr.hasNext){ // hasNext cannot be resolved or is not a field
            int object=itr.next(); //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to int
        return object; //Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Iterator<E>

            }
        }

    /** 
     * Returns the number of elements in this queue
     * @return the number of elements in this queue
     */
    public int size() {     
        return size;
    }

    /** 
     * Inserts the specified element into this queue, if possible
     * post:    The specified element is added to the rear of this queue
     * @param   x the element to insert
     * @return  true if it was possible to add the element 
     *          to this queue, else false
     */
    public boolean offer(E x) {
        QueueNode<E> q = new QueueNode<E>(x);
        if(last!=null){
        q.next=last.next;
        last.next=q;
        return true;

        } else {
        return true;
    }
    }

    /** 
     * Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, 
     * or null if this queue is empty.
     * post:    the head of the queue is removed if it was not empty
     * @return  the head of this queue, or null if the queue is empty 
     */
    public E poll() {
        if( last==null){
            return null;
        }
            QueueNode<E> n=last.next;   
            last.next=last.next.next;
            size=size-1;
            return n.element;

        }


    /** 
     * Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, 
     * returning null if this queue is empty
     * @return  the head element of this queue, or null 
     *          if this queue is empty
     */
    public E peek() {
        if(last==null){
            return null;
        }
        QueueNode<E> n=last;
        while(n.next !=null){

        }
        return n.element;
    }


    private static class QueueNode<E> {
        E element;
        QueueNode<E> next;

        private QueueNode(E x) {
            element = x;
            next = null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You can't call `.iterator()` on anything; your `QueueNode` doesn't appear to have an `iterator()` implementation.   You need to write a class that implements `Iterator` and fill in the `hasNext()`, `next()`, and `remove()` methods.

Comment: Vaseph 2 `QueueNode` it should be the queue of one element

Comment: Louis Wasserman so you mean that `Iterator itr = position.iterator();` is not necessary but ` while(itr.hasNext){` is necessary???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `iterator()` method needs to return an implementation of the `Iterator<E>` interface. You'd likely want to do this as a private inner class, so it has access to the queue fields.

The iterator class needs to keep the current position, and step through your nodes on calls to `next()`.

You might want to implement fail-fast logic to prevent issues with updating the queue while iterating. Add a change counter to the queue, and increment on change (insert/remove). Remember the change counter at the time the iterator is created, and if different on a call to `next()`, throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

This is a skeleton to get you started:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new FifoIterator();
}

private final class FifoIterator implements Iterator<E> {
    private QueueNode<E> curr;
    FifoIterator() {
        this.curr = FifoQueue.this.last;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (this.curr != null);
    }
    @Override
    public E next() {
        if (this.curr == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        this.curr = this.curr.next;
        E e = this.curr.element;
        if (this.curr == FifoQueue.this.last)
            this.curr = null;
        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of @Override and why you do multi subclasses  in your code and what does this mean `if (this.curr == FifoQueue.this.last)` why you wrote `FifoQueue` thanks

Comment: See javadoc of [@Override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html). --- Don't know what you mean by "multi subclasses". There is 1 inner class implementing an interface. No subclasses. --- Given your `poll()` implementation, your nodes are in a circular chain of `next` references, so if you keep advancing the iterator by going to `next`, when would you stop? Answer: When you're back where you started.